# Carousel CSS styling not being applied to HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am new to bootstrap and I'm using carousel for the first time however I'm having issues with styling. I tried to resize my image using CSS however there have been no changes. I will attach my code below. I am following a YouTube tutorial.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head> 
</html>
```

I'm sure I added bootstrap properly as well as the CSS file so I am unsure what the issue could be. I've also looked around on stack and all the solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used wrong element class name instead of .c-item use .carousel-item

```
.carousel-item{
height: 280px;
}

.c-img{
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
filter: brightness(0.6);
```

```css
.carousel-item{
    height: 280px;
}

.c-img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SpendingTracker | {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.discover-the-world.com/app/uploads/2018/08/norway-northern-tromso-surrounds-with-aurora-istk.jpg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="Slide 1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/63a32fa0d0e96ccdb4b9f8f3/Tromso-Aurora-Panorama-12-34-38-PM/960x0.jpg?format=jpg&width=960" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="Slide 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/105731796/750/422/image.jpg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="Slide 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried that and it didn't seem to work. Very confused

Answer (score 0):

First things first, it is **.carousel-item** and not **.c-item**.

Next, please make sure that your CSS file is being used by the html file.

Replace

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

With this tag

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And push this `link` tag to the end of your `head` tag (your styles should always override other styles).

Keep in mind that this solution will work if you have a folder called `css` containing the file `style.css` (not `styles.css`) at the same level of the `html` file.

Regards